# awk print line based on condition of a column

Tags: shell, awk

I have application logs and I need to print all lines with execution times exceeding 10000 ms. In the sample below only first line is printed since line 2 doesnt exceed 10k ms and line 3 doesn't show any execution time.

```
SERVICE_NAME:  | API: GetContents  | 20160927000511741 | EXECUTION TIME: 10130(ms)
SERVICE_NAME:  | API: GetContentsExtend  | 20160927000511741 | EXECUTION TIME: 22(ms)
SERVICE_NAME:  | API: GetContentsExtended  | 20160927000511741 | Current TN: -15698724705531331
```

I could do this by doing multiple steps

store execution value in a file:

```
cat logfile.log |   grep "EXECUTION TIME:" | awk '{print $NF}' | cut -d "(" -f1 | awk '{if ($1>9999) print $1}' >> input.txt
```

loop through this input file traversing the same log

```
cat input.txt | while read line 
do
cat logfile.log | grep $line"(ms)" >> output.txt
done
```

Can this be done maybe by a 1-liner command? Whats giving me a hard time is the execution time value has (ms) after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the execution time is >= 10000, then there will be at least 5 digits before the string "(ms)", so:

```
grep -E 'EXECUTION TIME: [[:digit:]]{5,}\(ms\)' filename
```

Comment: Stating the obvious, if the threshold changes to say, 1,234 instead of 1,000 then matching with a regexp isn't a great approach vs a numeric comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/EXECUTION TIME/ && ($NF+0)>=10000' file
SERVICE_NAME:  | API: GetContents  | 20160927000511741 | EXECUTION TIME: 10130(ms)
```

`$NF` is the last field on the line, e.g. the string `10130(ms)`. Adding zero to it converts the result to a number which means awk strips from the first non-digit (i.e. `(`) to the end off it and so it becomes the number `10130`. Then it's just a numeric comparison for `>=10000`.

Comment: Quite right. You might want to explain the mechanics of `($NF+0)` and how that turns "10130(ms)" into a number